# How to fix this syntax error for button onClick in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, syntax, buttonclick

I am a new learner software in PHP, so I try to do "button on click" in PHP with the object and I get the error message:
**" syntax error, unexpected '"'>"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) "**

this is my line of code:

```
$text .="<button onclick=alert"('" .$name. "\nIs Awesome!')"'>" . $name. "</button>";
```

Thank for help!

Comment: `$text .= "<button onclick='alert(\"$name\\n Is Awesome\")'>" . $name. "</button>";`

Answer (score 0):

`$text .="<button onclick=alert('" .$name. "\nIs Awesome!')>" . $name. "</button>";`

You had " bedore the opening ( which caused the error